# Is there a way to figure out how often a SharePoint user clicked on a SiteCollection?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, activitylog

I'd like to know if there is a way to figure out how often a SharePoint (2013) user clicked on a SiteCollection or Web. Is there a specific service that is capable of the logging or is there a log in the database anyway? My idea is to display the result as a graph. For example:

(user a)-[40 clicks]->(SiteCollection X)<-[60 clicks]-(user b)

Answer (score 0):

Read this for analytics in Sharepoint

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219554.aspx

But, if this report is important to you I strongly recommend using something like [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) (which is free of course) to track the data by your self.

You can create your own account, and send an event each time user enters your site or web.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did some more research and found the "SharePoint audit log reports". They do almost exactly what I want. Information about how often items in a SiteCollection have been clicked is provided and reports are saved as exel sheets. [Example](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131)

Comment: Great! , So Answer your own question so others can see it :J

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and found the "SharePoint audit log reports". They do almost exactly what I want. Information about how often items in a SiteCollection have been clicked is provided and reports are saved as exel sheets. [Example](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131)